# Load blade view file from cache in Laravel

Tags: laravel, caching

I'm trying to store a whole blade view with param in cache for first load and load it from cache in next time reload.

Here is what I did:

```
public function cacheAction()
{
    $data = $this->model->getContent();
    Cache::remember('cache-view', 1800, function() {
        dd('load from cache!');
        return view('index')->render();
    });
    dd('not load from cache!');
    return view('index', ['data' => $data]);
    
}
```

I added 2 lines debug notice when load page. But when I access page, it always show "not loaded from cache!" for anytime.

How I can fix this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it the other way around here. When your function in the `remember` callback runs then it is **not** loaded from cache. When it does not run then it is loaded from cache. However you are not actually using the result from the cache here. Here's what you can do to utilise the cache:

```
public function cacheAction()
{
    $view = Cache::remember('cache-view', 1800, function() {
        $data = $this->model->getContent();
        return view('index', ['data' => $data]);
    });
    return $view;    
}
```

Note that your `cache-view` cache key does not actually depend on the content of `$data` so if `$data` changes you will get a stale cached view. Here's how to get around this:

```
public function cacheAction()
{
    $data = $this->model->getContent();
    $cacheKey = md5(serialize($data)); // Make sure data is serializable
    $view = Cache::remember('cache-view-'.$cacheKey, 1800, function() use ($data) {
        return view('index', ['data' => $data]);
    });
    return $view;    
}
```

However this does have the drawback of always reading `$data` to check if the cache is stale. Which solution works for you depends on how static or dynamic your data is. If you don't expect data to change frequently then people seeing stale data for at most 1800 seconds might not be a big issue

Comment: I asked myself this question: If data is not inside the cache remember function, the cache will not help a lot, since the view itself is cached by Laravel anyway. `$data` is never used in the example code.

Comment: if I put $data = $this->model->getContent(); into cache callback function, $data is not pass to my view. I tried dd($data) in my view but it have nothing

Comment: @Tomato putting `dd($data)` in the view won't work because the view is cached so `dd` won't be part of the cached code. If you put `dd` in the view before caching it the `dd` will prevent the view from being cached.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the return value of the remember function: you will always get to the `dd()` function because the return statement is inside the remember callback function.

```
public function cacheAction()
{
    
    $return = Cache::remember('cache-view', 1800, function() {
        dump('new cache created');
        $data = $this->model->getContent();
        return view('index', ['data' => $data]);
    });
    dd('this will show every time, even if loaded by cache');
    return $return;
    
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! I changed my code to this but my $data variable is not pass to my view. I tried dd($data) in view but it have nothing